# How to rotate the Postgresql credentials using REST in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Heroku Postgres database and I'd like to rotate the credentials from REST. It would be trivial on the command line ([source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-credentials)):

```
heroku pg:credentials DATABASE --reset
```

How do you do the same thing in pure REST? The closest I could find was to obtain the details of the add-on:

```
# The ID was obtained from https://api.heroku.com/apps/myexampleapp/addons
curl -n -X GET https://api.heroku.com/apps/myexampleapp/addons/5ebb9a9e-b340-4a62-afb5-de0c99fd0fad \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"

{
  "config_vars":[
    "HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER_URL"
  ],
  "created_at":"2015-02-02T11:09:33Z",
  "id":"5ebb9a9e-b340-4a62-afb5-de0c99fd0fad",
  "name":"heroku-postgresql-amber",
  "addon_service":{
    "id":"6c67493d-8fc2-4cd4-9161-4f1ec11cbe69",
    "name":"Heroku Postgres"
  },
  "plan":{
    "id":"062a1cc7-f79f-404c-9f91-135f70175577",
    "name":"heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"
  },
  "app":{
    "id":"cccccccc-ffff-4444-bbbb-dddddddddddd",
    "name":"myexampleapp"
  },
  "provider_id":"resource8637857@heroku.com",
  "updated_at":"2015-02-02T11:09:33Z"
}
```

But I don't succeed to reset/rotate the credentials using a `POST https://api.heroku.com/apps/myexampleapp/addons/5ebb9a9e-b340-4a62-afb5-de0c99fd0fad/reset` or similar. What is the right command?

Comment: The URL would rather be ```https://postgres-starter-api.heroku.com/client/v11/databases/imagining-aptly-0000/credentials_rotation```, but it keeps answering "Internal Server Error". Maybe my ```Authorization``` header isn't correct.

Comment: I've tried to understand [the go client][1], but I don't understand how the authentication works - It may be different between api.heroku.com and postgres-starter-api.heroku.com, obviously. [1] https://github.com/heroku/hk/tree/master/postgresql